# CSS Sticky footer issue

Tags: css, sticky-footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS sticky footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906065/css-sticky-footer)

I am trying to implement the CSS sticky footer but for some reason there is a margin between the footer and bottom of the following page:

http://berrisford.gumpshen.com/

The same thing happens here:

http://berrisford.gumpshen.com/jobs/executive/senior-executive/

Any help would reall be appreciated

Comment: You should take a look at the solutions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488565/how-to-stick-a-footer-to-bottom-in-css

Comment: If the solutions from the question pointed by @James fixes the issue, I'd suggest to close this question as duplicate.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. The content I have is managed by a CMS meaning the content can expand below the fold of a page, in this instance the position absolute bottom wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
    /* No need for margin here */
}
```

This won't work on Internet Explorer older than 7. I'm not sure about the bugs in IE7, IE8 or newer.

Comment: `position: fixed` is not remotely the point of the sticky footer. -1

Comment: I also needed `width: 100%` when testing in chrome and ie8 and no need for `left` or `right`.

Comment: @Matt Whats the point of a sticky footer if not to stick on the page?

Comment: @James: You can set `left` and `right` and leave `width` as `auto`, as the browser will calculate the width based on the other properties. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width (actually, setting `width: 100%` might get you in trouble if you have margin/padding/border, unless you also set `box-sizing`)

Comment: @denilson From my testing in chrome: It would seem that `left/right` or `width` doesn't make any difference in this case. but it you don't put either it doesn't strech out.

Comment: @James this is the typical behavior implied by the phrase "CSS sticky footer:" http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: @James: because `position: fixed` is not the typical "sticky footer."

Comment: @MAtt he didn't ask for the typical sticky footer and specifically asked for non-`position: absolute` solution. And therefore this answer is still good. It works and  does not have any real issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have `margin-top:-60px;` which is too much apparently. Bring that down to `margin-top:-45px;` or so

Answer (score 0):

Please give `padding-bottom:20px` for container ID. I think it will works

```
#container {
width: 940px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```