# displacement of a single HTML element at the opening of another

Tags: html, css, position, footer

Look at my problem: 
[image]

How to make so that when you open popup window your footer shifted down?

some css here:

```
#advanced_search_div_body {
height: 100%;
width: 817;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
display: table;
background-color: white;
}

#foot {
padding: 30px 0px;
background-color: black;
clear: both;
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 2;

}
```

Comment: Please provide more code

Comment: Your width is missing a unit (`817` should probably be `817px`)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to tell footer to be down of the page.

So, basically change #foot position: relative to absolute. Try this:

```
position:absolute;
width:100%;
bottom:0px;
```

Or something like:

```
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
```

Comment: maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488565/how-to-stick-a-footer-to-bottom-in-css

Answer (score 0):

the trick is a pusher div:

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
    display:block;
}
#pusher{
    display:block;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nLKLh/1/

Comment: cant understand, where to add pusher div

Comment: just put put it over all your other stuff in the body except the footer.