# How to bring the footer to the very bottom?

Tags: css

I am currently working on a webpage and in the process, I am trying to bring a div whose id is "footer" to the extreme bottom. It worked at first, but when I placed a marquee in my page, the div came about 50px higher.

How can I avoid this? The method I used to place the footer to the extreme bottom was by styling it by the following syntax:

```
#footer{ position:absolute;bottom:0;}
```

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle as an example?

Comment: marquee is deprecated for use, instead use jquery or css3 animations...

Comment: You're using a marquee?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stick a footer to bottom in css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488565/how-to-stick-a-footer-to-bottom-in-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkout this [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

However, marquee tag is quite old and you should'nt be used anymore at least with HTML5

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/4zbah6de/1/)

html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <!-- Header start -->
        <h1>How to keep footers at the bottom of the page (CSS demo)</h1>
        <!-- Header end -->
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <!-- Body start -->
        <p>In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal. Read the In this demo the footer is pushed to the bottom of the screen in all standards compliant web browsers even when there is only a small amount of content on the page. This with work with IE 6 and IE 5.5 too. Non-standards compliant browsers degrade gracefully by positioning the footer under the content as per normal.</p>
        <!-- Body end -->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <!-- Footer start -->
        <p><strong>Footer</strong> (always at the bottom).</p>
        <!-- Footer end -->
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#container {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#header {
    background:#ff0;
    padding:10px;
}
#body {
    padding:10px;
    padding-bottom:60px;
    /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    /* Height of the footer */
    background:#6cf;
}
/* other non-essential CSS */
 #header p, #header h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 0 0 10px;
}
#footer p {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Note : If your body content is long enough your footer will be at the bottom of the page. If content is short enough it will stick at the bottom of screen.