# Make footer stay at bottom when viewing on all devices?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I view the website on a mobile device, the footer div is halfway up the page (on my desktop PC its at the bottom).

Nothing yet as not sure where to start. tried `position:absolute;` in the CSS of the footer to no avail.

CSS

```
#footer {
    width:1460px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#FF0;
    font-weight: bold;  
}
```

HTML

```
<div id = "footer"> <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function scrollToBottom() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 
'slow');
    }
    function scrollToTop() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:scrollToTop()"><img src="images/scroll.png" 
alt="Scroll to Top" title="Scroll to Top" width="42" height="37" 
hspace="65" vspace="20" />                 </a><a 
href="http://www.facebook.com/woodzyweb" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Woodzy','','images/wwd_roll.png',1)"><img 
src="images/wwd.png" alt="Visit Our web Designer Facebook Page" 
name="Woodzy" width="150" height="47" border="0" id="Woodzy" /> 
</a>website designed by:</div>
```

No error messages that I'm aware of; just wish to fix footer to the bottom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stick a footer to bottom in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488565/how-to-stick-a-footer-to-bottom-in-css)

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways to go about it,  you could either change the #footer css to:

```
#footer {
    width:1460px;
    height:80px;
    background-color:#FF0;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
}
```

You could also set the div that contains all the content above the footer to be a minimum height of the viewport:

```
#container {
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Have tried this on the "charities that we've helped page" (www.perrywoodcharityday.000webhostapp.com /charities.html) but still shows up incorrectly when I view on mobile so I'm guessing my amateur knowledge has meant I've messed up elsewhere. Can anyone view the page source and advise?

Comment: The url for your website is broke

Comment: Sorry, it should be this one - https://perrywoodcharityday.000webhostapp.com/charities.html

Comment: never mind you want it to be position: fixed;  if you are talking about the footer always being present