# Bootstrap - how can I push the below element down once the above has grown?

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling with one thing. I'm iterating objects which create some sort of row table (the new one is always below the previous one). I tried to add footer but the issue arises when I'm displaying more than 18 elements per page, it overlaps it:

Example:
[image]

My html:

```
<body>
    <div id="main" class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <div class="container h-100">
            {% include 'navbar.html' %}
            {% block content %}{%endblock%}
        </div>
        {% include 'footer.html' %}
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'js/vue2.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

How can I make this table to push the footer all the way down depends on its size ?

@edit
footer:

```
<footer class="bg-dark text-white text-center text-lg-start">
    <div class="container p-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                <h5 class="text-uppercase">fastIT</h5>
                <p>
                    Find more
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                <h5 class="text-uppercase">Links</h5>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!" class="text-white">Project</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!" class="text-white">Scraping sources</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!" class="text-white">Rules</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)">
        © 2020 Copyright:
        <a class="text-white" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/">ledi12</a>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can you share the footer code and its styling if it has any?

Comment: Also does this answer your question? [How to stick a footer to bottom in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488565/how-to-stick-a-footer-to-bottom-in-css)

Comment: @AjayLingayat added my footer code